# Running a python script to update accounts?

Tags: python

Sorry if this should be inherently obvious, but I'm a total newbie at SalesForce.

I need to update a large number of customer accounts that we have in our system based off a .csv that I have locally on my machine, and since I have a working knowledge of python, I was hoping to use that to write a script to do it for me (I don't really want to manually update 1000+ accounts). Is this even possible? I've been looking around a lot, but it seems to me that I would have to create an app just for this one time update- which I don't really want to do nor do I have the permissions.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you familiar with SFDC dataloader tool, is there a reason you are not considering using it here?

Answer (score 0):

If the csv has the Salesforce Id, or an external I'd, you could use the data loader as suggested in the comment or the data import wizard, since it's less than 50k records